# duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios

```
Ld /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.app/QuizUsingDB normal i386
    cd "/Users/ankit/Desktop/iOS Examples/QuizUsingDB"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/Objects-normal/i386/QuizUsingDB.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -lsqlite3 -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/Objects-normal/i386/QuizUsingDB_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.app/QuizUsingDB

duplicate symbol _flag in:
    /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/Objects-normal/i386/MediumViewController.o
    /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimpleQuestionViewController.o
duplicate symbol _flag in:
    /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/Objects-normal/i386/MediumViewController.o
    /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/Objects-normal/i386/HardViewController.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. You're missing the Q bit.

Comment: when I build my project i get this above error...

Comment: Do you have constant named _flag?

Comment: Maybe you could add a little commentary above your error message explaining what you've done, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: yeh i have a constant named flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have constant with the same name: `flag` in multiple files: `MediumViewController`, `SimpleQuestionViewController` and `HardViewController`.

Please rename it in one of them.

Comment: or it could be variable defined outside class scope once in both classes. it occurs when copy pasting classes with variables defined outside the scope of class.

Comment: which two files are you talking about??

Comment: MediumViewController, SimpleQuestionViewController and HardViewController .h or .m.

Answer (score 0):

That error means there is more than one static variable in your project with the same name.  This could happen a few different ways.

problem case 1:

.h file 1:

```
#import ...

int flag;

@interface
@end
```

.h file 2:

```
#import ...

int flag;

@interface
@end
```

Then if these two .h files are included in your project you have two global variables named flag.  That is bad.

Problem case 2:

You have a .h file with a global variable imported in multiple .m files.

.h

```
#import ...

int flag;

@interface
@end
```

.m file 1:

```
#import "your.h"
```

.m file 2:

```
#import "your.h"
```

Both of those .m files create a global variable named `flag` when you import the .h file defining it.

One way of avoiding problem case 1 is to rename the global variable.  One way of avoiding problem 2 is using the `extern` modifier in the .h file, then defining the variable in a .m file that `#import`s your .h file.  It could be several other problems, but those are the two that I can think of right off.

.h file:

```
#import ...

extern int flag;

@interface
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "your.h"

int flag

@implementation 
@end
```

Make sure you only define the flag variable in one .m file that imports your .h file, otherwise you will have duplicate variable errors again.